# Editing the sudoers file on Mac or Linux when you have no permissions

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to install something on my MacOS (or Linux) system and I don't have permission because I'm not the admin.  So I tried using `sudo` and it says that I'm not in `/etc/sudoers` file.  I've tried editing the `sudoers` file but it won't let me, so I "googled" it.  Everybody says to use `visudo` to edit the file.  The problem is, it won't even let me use `visudo`!  When I type "visudo" it just says

```
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Would appreciate some help.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried switching users and then editing the sudoers file but still didn't work

Comment: here is the detailed solution with logs:
https://iosdose.com/user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be `root` (or have `root`privileges) in order to use the `visudo` command and edit the `sudoers` file

Answer (score 0):

If u messed up your sudoers file.You'll need to:

- Reboot into recovery mode (hit escape during boot, choose the recovery mode option on the grub screen)
- Choose the 'Enable networking' option (if you don't your filesystem will be mounted as read-only. who knew)
- Chosee the 'Drop to root shell' option
- run visudo, fix your file
- Reboot with normal grub option

source :- http://mario.net.au/content/recover-etcsudoers-ubuntu-1204

Answer (score 0):

You have to be root or use sudo to edit the sudoers file.

```
sudo visudo
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to mac.  Very annoyed by the time=0 for sudoer (you havew to type the password every time you use sudo). I want to increase this value to a reasonable number:
timestamp_timeout=30.
After adding the above line to the /etc/sudoers file, I could not login as su anymore because the parser fails to read the sudoers file.
This posting is to document how I fix this problem.

```
1. Restart your mac
2. Hold on to Command-R two keys until you see the progress bar.
3. Start a new terminal, this terminal will be the root terminal
4. Edit the invalid sudoers file.  Note this file is not in /etc/sudoers when you loggedin in as root
```

The full path is: 
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/etc
restart then you are happy again.

This method will also apply to users who are not in the sudoers list and want to add themselves to the list.

Note: if you could not find the sudoers file as root use find:

find / -name sudoers