# How-to-fix-“username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file.-This-incident-will-be-reported”

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to enable the mod_rewrite on Apache, I used Putty to access the server on my windows OS. 
I logged in using my username and password, My friend said that I should have root access to enable the mod_rewrite, so he advice me to type sudo su after I successfully log in. So I added sudo su command and it asked me a password again, so I type my password but I got an error.

```
[myusername] is not in the sudoers file.the incident will be reported
```

So maybe anyone here could help me.

Comment: Well, I suggest you ask your friend, maybe he simply forgot to add you to the `sudoers` file?

Comment: Or you are logged in to a system running an operating system based on a distribution that follows the second logic of using `sudo`: that you have to type the password of the account you want to impersonate to be granted that right. To be able to do so you then would need to know the password of the `root` account.

Comment: You see: _we_ cannot tell you, since we do not know the system. You and your friend know the system.

Comment: thanks arkascha,  is it possible for me(login using my username and password) and  add [myuser] to the sudoers file? or there is anything else I can do to have a root privilige?

Comment: Well obviously that is not possible, since that would mean that you could grant yourself privileges. That does not really make sense, does it?

Comment: What you _can_ do is: ask the system administrator to add you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806576/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported)

Comment: Also a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396678/editing-the-sudoers-file-on-mac-or-linux-when-you-have-no-permissions

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new user into sudo group  in debian based systems *(Ubuntu, kbuntu, debian, etc)* and the wheel group under RedHat based systems *(RedHat, Fedora, CentOS, etc)* by using the following commands

```
usermod -a -G sudo user
or
usermod -a -G wheel user
```

Answer (score 2):

1. restart your machine
2. choose Advance ubuntu option
3. then go for the root option
4. you are now root here, root@machine:

> 5. enter: usermod -aG sudo username

now you have added the user to sudo group, you can exit from root and login as a user.
you can do this without restarting your machine if your root password is updated,
by default it is not but if not, then you have to restart and set the root password by **passwd** command.

But if you already have a root password setup
enter:

> **su -**

and you will be root,
but recommended is to use:

> sudo -s

as a temporary root access

Answer (score 1):

In the shell command line, type:

```
su -
```

After that, enter the same password for your ubuntu user.

In order to add your user to the sudo group, type:

```
adduser <youruser> sudo
```

Restart your Linux system to finished it.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to add this user in a sudo group. You can do this, first, accessing the system using an admin user, next taking access to superuser mod:

> sudo su

Then, you can add a user you need in a sudo group using the following commands:

> adduser [username] sudo

Answer (score 0):

su root
nano /etc/sudoers
Then add the user below admin user like below syntax.
user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to the root user:

> su -

2. Edit the sudoers file using the visudo command:

> visudo

3. In the sudoers file, locate the line that looks like:

> %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

4. Below that line, add the following line to allow the user "your_username" to use sudo:

> your_username   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

5. Save and exit the sudoers file.(ctrl+x) If you are using the visudo command, it will prompt you to save the changes before exiting.